# Understanding the TCP packet size limit with UDP packet size limit & what it means at boost::asio level of programming

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio` to do `UDP` as well as `TCP communication` in my Client app & Server applications. I found that I am only able to transmit data of size `65535 bytes` using `UDP` as it seems to be the max packet size in UDP.

The max packet size limit is also there in `TCP` which is `65535 bytes` ? But I am able send chunks larger than max packet size using `boost::asio::write` in `TCP` & read it all fine on the client app. I see that I don't have to bother about the max packet size in TCP but in UDP I have ensure each `socket.send_to` is done with a buffer smaller than `max packet size`

***How does this work ?*** Is this because `TCP` is stream based takes care of creating packets at the lower layer ? 
Is there some way I can increase the `max packet size` in `UDP` ?

*Is it possible that some of the bytes of an `UDP packet` I sent from server side could be missing when I read on client side ? If yes, then is there way **only to detect the loss** on client side of UDP ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP takes care of transmission control (that's actually what T and C stand for in TCP). You usually don't bother with the amount of data you send to a TCP socket, because it manages on its own how much data to send in each packet. Each TCP packet can have up to 65536 bytes of payload, but you usually don't think about it, because TCP is rather complex and can do a lot of things.

UDP however lacks any control mechanism and kept as simple as possible, so you need to decide how much data to send with each packet. Maximal size is again 65536 bytes because you have only two bytes in the UDP headers to specify the length of a message. Another thing to consider when deciding on a UDP packet size is the fact that lower level protocols have their own limits too (65K for IP, ~1500 bytes for ethernet).

You can't increase the maximum size of a UDP packet and you generally don't want to do it because large UDP packets can be dropped without any notice. Other answers on SO suggest using 512-8K packets for datagrams over internet.

It is possible to receive a UDP datagram with damaged bytes (not "missing" though). But each packet is covered by a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) so a client will know if the datagram has been damaged in transition.

Comment: how do I do a checksum based check with boost::asio UDP ? Please suggest if you could

Comment: @AdaLovelace you don't need to do anything about it, checksums are part of the UDP protocol. You already have this check.

Comment: Note that the checksum is optional in IPv4. However, if a packet is received it also has to pass the Ethernet checksum.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not so much related to `UDP` and `TCP`, as it is to `IP`.
`UDP` and `TCP` are transport protocols, which does not define a maximum packet (or segment) size. 
`IP` is a network protocol. An `IP` packet can contains at most 65536 (2^16) bytes, since there are two bytes used to define the packet size. 
Large `IP` packets are divided into segments. If one of the segments is lost, or corrupted, then the entire `IP` packet is lost. The size of the segments depends on the link layer protocol, usually Ethernet. For Ethernet the usual maximum size is 1500 bytes at most, or more if jumbo frames are allowed.

So, if you transmit `UDP` packets larger than 1500 bytes it may be divided into several segments. This is normally fine, if there are no losses on the network. However, if there are losses the impact will only be bigger when there are more dependent segments. For example, consider a network with 1% losses, if you transmit a `UDP` packet of 65536 bytes, the it will most likely be divided into 44 segments. The probability of this packet being received is then: (1-0.01)^44 = 64 %...

This is also why many TCP implementations and UDP based applications use at most 1500 bytes packets.

Extracting corrupted packets is a nontrivial task, look for libraries like `libpcap`.